Finding Common Neighbors between Graph Nodes
I am working on an Application that will generate a graph where each node is either a disease or its symptom. This is an undirected graph, and there is an edge between the disease and its symptoms.
Given a list of Symptoms, I need to find out the set of the most likely diseases.
The way I have approached this is by creating the graph, then finding the neighbors of each of the symptoms, then finding out which of them are common across the symptoms.
Problems :

If two symptoms have nothing in common, then the results do not show anything
It does not show the most likely disease, even when I input the exact list of symptoms from the dataset.

How do I fix this?

It seems you are dealing with a bipartite graph $G= (X\cup Y, E)$. Here, you represent diseases as the nodes constituting one vertex set $X$, while $Y$ is the set of vertices corresponding to the symptoms. You only put edges between $X$ and $Y$.
Now let $N(v)$ denote the set of neighbouring vertices of a vertex $v$. For the first problem, you basically want to find the intersection of such neighbour sets. Formally given a list of symptoms $S\subseteq Y$, you report $D = \bigcap\limits_{v\in S} N(v)$ for the first problem. Note $D$ can be empty as well.
For the second problem, there is no straight-forward answer! Because for a given list of symptoms, you can have multiple possibilities in $D$. Now it becomes a bit subjective, and your input does not indicate any quantifiable way to tackle this. It might be possible if you assign some weights to edges so that you may rank the items in $D$ in some way.

For the first one, I do want it to show something. Like something in between the intersection and the union. I basically want to give the doctor just a shortened list of possible diseases that he can use to help with his diagnosis.
Do you have any suggestions for that?

If you somehow assign some edge weights for the likelihood of a disease for a given symptom, it is surely possible. You just report the diseases with maximum likelihoods. Here, the main research challenge is to design a good metric to capture the likelihood, the rest might be relatively straightforward. E.g., you can take the weighted sum of the diseases and then report only a few of the maximum weighted ones.
